# How to edit product page template in Magento

Tags: magento

I want to customize the product page template file on my Magento site. I couldn't find a way to customize my product page template. Anybody please specify the exact file and the location of that file. I am using Magento version 1.7.0.2

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can find all the templates related to product view in the following directory.

```
Magento/app/design/frontend/default/your_theme/template/catalog/product/
```

You can customize more (if you want to know which template is for that particular block) with template path hints

```
http://www.pauldonnelly.net/magento-turning-on-template-path-hints/
```

**UPDATE:**

Copying content from the above link, in case the link may no longer exist.

**What is Template Path hints**

*Template Path Hints are little tags which would lie on top of your shop frontend. These little tags enable you to view where exactly the code of a specific element is stored within your file structure. Bottom line Template Path Hints saves you alot of frustration.*

**How to turn on Template Path Hints?**

1. Open the admin control panel
2. Open the system tab and select configuration
3. Select Main Website or Name of your website (NOT DEFAULT CONFIG) from the Current Configuration Scope drop down
4. Select Developer on the left sidebar
5. Open the Debug drop down
6. Set Template Path Hints To Yes
7. Click on Save Config to save down your changes

Comment: If your_theme does not have templates than copy them from base theme. Only copy which are necessary.

Comment: Thanks @dushyant-joshi for the reply. I have tried earlier to apply template hints on Magento admin but couldn't find that "Template Path Hints". Can you figure out where I am wrong. Thanks

Comment: You can find that in debug section. You need to select "your store view"  from "Current Configuration Scope" drop down

Comment: Thanks @dushyant-joshi for the reply. I found the "Template Path Hints". Thanks for your time.

Comment: I check the base and theme product/view.phtml page for the change the template but it is not working...