# Different .phtml to diffrent type of product

Tags: magento, view, frontend, product

I am trying to make module that switches diffrent .phtml of productview depend on attributeset name. I dont know witch file is responsible for rendering productview.

Comment: see the similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16933603/how-to-edit-product-page-template-in-magento/16933682#16933682

Comment: thats not the solution - i need php file that render layout , no .phtml :-)

Comment: You can have Blocks enabled as hint too along with phtml files

Answer (score 1):

It is usually Magento Block that render template. In your case productivew is rendered by

```
Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View.
```

You can easily figure this out by enabling `template_hints` and `template_hints_blocks`. To enable these to option follow steps below:

1. Go go Admin
2. System > Configuration
3. In left column, Select Developer under Advance.
4. Change Current Configuration Scope to website level (`template_hints` and `template_hints_blocks` is applicable at website level only)
5. Make yes to Template Path Hints and Add Block Names to Hints under Debug group.

Answer (score 0):

you can rewrite this class:

```
Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View
```

and then you can add your own logic to it to switch to another template, not the standard

```
catalog/product/view.phtml
```