# Editing product attribute in magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.9.1

I want to edit magento product page informations ( ex : attributes and options )
So, i edited  app/design/frontend/default/myTemplate/template/catalog/product/view.phtml

I found this code `<?php echo $this->getChildChildHtml('container1', '', true, true) ?>`

Which is showing product info , like selct different color...

and i want to edit this info, 
working website link :`http://www.milwebstudio.com/dravano/bed/test-configure-product2.html`

I follow this `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16933603/how-to-edit-product-page-template-in-magento`

and other resources . But still can't figure out , how can i edit this product info or step level ...

please visit my side to see my problems .

Comment: you mean you want to change the text "Select different color" ? The label of attribute ?

Comment: no.. actually  after select the color , (Ex: Red color )now its display , another option for choosing  price and again another dropdown , i don't want to this . So, After choose color , want to go in step 2 (which is size).