# Magento - Edit Product Page html not working

Tags: html, magento, magento-1.9, product

I'm trying to edit the HTML of product page from Magento but it's not working. 
I followed some tutorials (example: [How to edit product page template in Magento](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16933603/how-to-edit-product-page-template-in-magento)) but without success.

I'm editing the "view.phtml" from the path below (standard template):
/*siteName*/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/product

[Edited code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k5XJK.png)

[HTML not updated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YzqBv.png)

Any idea?

Thx.

Comment: As a rule, it's better to post actual code than pictures of it.

Comment: first write a log for getJsonConfig(), see if any data is returned or not.

Comment: Hello, thx for the answer. Where I write a log at getJsonConfig? And writing it will be possible to change the **view.phtml** file?

Answer (score 0):

This file call based on theme so please check your theme folder, the path of this file follow.

```
/siteName/app/design/frontend/[theme folder]/[theme child folder]/template/catalog/product/view.phtml
```

Comment: Hi, thx for the answer. I'm testing my solution so I'm using the default template. I'm trying to change this file: **/siteName/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/product/view.phtml**.  Is it the correct path?

Comment: are you using rwd theme or default ?

Comment: if you are using default then path will be `app/design/frontend/default/default/template/catalog/product/view.phtml` if you are using rwd then `app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/catalog/product/view.phtml`

Comment: I didn't know that this *rwd* them exist. I changed the file on the /rwd/... and everything looks fine now! Thx @Sunny!

Comment: if this answer help to you then please accept this so other can solve the problem with having same problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the RWD (responsive) theme you may possibly need to edit the template in that folder structure.  It is new in 1.9.x